Load Buttons in real time when created | WPF
I'm new to WPF and I'm trying to dynamically add x amount of radiobutton to my navigation panel in my form. I have already successfully read the file that stores the names of each button and produce each button corresponding to their names. The code for that is below:
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // get textbox string
            string textboxContent = Panel_Name_Textbox.Text;

            // check # of panels
            if(panelHandler.PanelSpaceAvailable()) 
            {
                // if user is allowed more panels
                // create panel - this also stores data in file
                panelHandler.CreatePanel(textboxContent);

                // display successful message
                string title = "Panel Created";
                string message = $"The Panel '{textboxContent}' has been successfully created!";
                PopupWindow("success", title, message);

            } else
            {
                // else, display error
                string title = "Error";
                string message = "You are at the maximum panel limit of 8 panels.";
                PopupWindow("error", title, message);
            }
        }

Here is my MainViewModel.cs code:
       private readonly ObservableCollection<PanelButtons> _dataButtons = new ObservableCollection<PanelButtons>();
       public ObservableCollection<PanelButtons> DataButtons { get { return _dataButtons; } }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            HomeVM = new StartingHomeViewModel();
            SettingsVM = new SettingsViewModel();

            CurrentView = HomeVM;

            HomeViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
            {
                CurrentView = HomeVM;
            });

            SettingsViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
            {
                CurrentView = SettingsVM;
            });


            // The code below should be the only relavent code for this question
            PanelHandler panelHandler = new PanelHandler();

            // get names of each button saved in file
            List<string> panelNameList = panelHandler.PanelNameCollection();

            // for each name (button to be made), create new PanelButton and add to collection
            foreach (string panelName in panelNameList)
            {
                PanelButtons data = new PanelButtons(panelName);
                DataButtons.Add(data);

            }

        }

Here is my MainWindow.xaml that shows each radiobutton:
<ItemsControl 
    ItemsSource="{Binding DataButtons}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}"
                         Content="{Binding ButtonName}"
                         Height="50"
                        FontSize="14"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>

And here is my PanelButtons.cs:
    internal class PanelButtons
    {
        public string ButtonName { get; set; }

        public PanelButtons(string buttonName)
        {
            ButtonName = buttonName;
        }
    }

In summary, I'm new to WPF and XAML and am curious how I would go about automatically updating the public ObservableCollection<PanelButtons> DataButtons so when a user prompts the Button_Click it will add the new radiobutton to my navigation panel.
I will say that everything else works as needed, I just have to restart the program to see the new button in the navigation. I need it to be added in real time.

It is unclear how exactly your code is supposed to work, but is seems clear that calling panelHandler.CreatePanel(textboxContent); will not magically add an element to the DataButtons collection in the view model. So how are you going to implement that - or is that your question?

panelHandler handles all the file methods for the panel class, which is composed of a panelID and panelName. So yes, how would I go about adding it in real time, rather than just in my MainViewModel.cs file? Do I need to access the observable collection from my Button_Click event and add it there?

I forgot to mention that panelHandler.CreatePanel() creates a new panel instance and saves all panel instances to a file. It does not create anything on the UI, I just don't know the best way to go about adding the new data to the collection.

You are creating a PanelHandler instance in the MainViewModel constructor, and then you add a new PanelButtons object for each string that is returned from panelHandler.PanelNameCollection() to the DataButtons property. Why is there no equivalent code in MainViewModel that would add another PanelButtons after calling panelHandler.CreatePanel(...). Why are there different instances of PanelHandler at all, one in the vuiew model and one in the view?

All the PanelHandler-related code should be in MainViewModel, and you would call an appropriate CreatePanel method by casting the view's DataContext, like ((MainViewModel)DataContext).CreatePanel(textboxContent); CreatePanel would obviously call DataButtons.Add(...).

I see what you're saying - that makes alot of sense lol. Let me adjust my code and I'll get back to you.

just what I needed brother. Thank you for your help! @clemens

The next step could be to wrap the CreatePanel method in an ICommand property and bind the Button's Command to that property instead of accessing the view model in a Click handler.

That's a great idea and sounds like a better way to handle it. I'll be checking that out now

It's "button content"; or text. It's not "Names" you're binding to. And you don't have "property changed" implemented on the "data object". "Collection changes" are not the same as "property changes" (IMO).

Better declare the ButtonName property read-only, as public string ButtonName { get; }. There is no need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged - if that was meant with you don't have "property changed" implemented.

It is also unnecessary to have a private field for the read-only DataButtons property. You could declare it as public ObservableCollection<PanelButtons> DataButtons { get; } = new ObservableCollection<PanelButtons>();

Without a "volume" estimate, the whole design process is called into question. There also seems to be some confusion regarding "common interface standards" when it comes to radio buttons versus check boxes. And "automatically" adding property changed logic (where you are already binding) solves more problems than it (ever) creates (as witnessed by the "answer").

Here is a very simple example of how to do what you are thinking. Note, I tied the button back to code behind to keep it simple and highlight the binding aspect. This should be plenty to get you started with a working example.
I also set d:DataContext to the ViewModel. This will give you intellisense when binding things. It's super handy.
MainWindow Definition
<Window
    x:Class="TestWpfApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpfApp"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MainViewModel,
                                     IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <DockPanel>
        <Button
            Width="120"
            Height="40"
            Margin="5"
            Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"
            Content="Add Radio Button"
            DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" />
        <ItemsControl
            Margin="5"
            ItemsSource="{Binding PanelButtonVms}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate
                    DataType="{x:Type local:PanelButtonVm}">
                    <RadioButton
                        Height="50"
                        BorderBrush="Black"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        Content="{Binding ButtonName}"
                        FontSize="14" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

        </ItemsControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>

Code Behind
using System.Windows;

namespace TestWpfApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
            DataContext = MainViewModel;  // Have to set the MainWindow's DataContext.
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is just to be able to tie to the code behind button click even.
        /// Normally I would bind the button to a RelayCommand in the ViewModel,
        /// but this is just to show an example.
        /// </summary>
        private MainViewModel MainViewModel {
            get;
        }

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            var count = MainViewModel.PanelButtonVms.Count;
            MainViewModel.PanelButtonVms.Add(new PanelButtonVm{ButtonName = $"I'm button #{count}"});
        }
    }
}

ViewModel Definitions
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace TestWpfApp
{
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
        public ObservableCollection<PanelButtonVm> PanelButtonVms {
            get;
        } = new ();

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null) {
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                                         new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public class PanelButtonVm : INotifyPropertyChanged {

        public string ButtonName {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null) {
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                                         new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

Output Window

